# Is it possible to issue a select query in mysql without taking any read locks?

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb, myisam

It seems that mysql select content (as opposed to e.g. count) queries always take at least a table read lock on myisam tables and a row read lock on innodb tables. Is there a way to issue a select content query in mysql (I could change table type if that's required) without having it to grab any locks? I don't mind if the data returned is inconsistent since I will use it for a search index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [InnoDB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb.html) you achieve this by setting the transaction isolation level to: `READ UNCOMMITTED`.

In this isolation level:

> SELECT statements are performed in a
>   nonlocking fashion, but a possible
>   earlier version of a row might be
>   used. Thus, using this isolation
>   level, such reads are not consistent.
>   This is also called a “dirty read.”
>   Otherwise, this isolation level works
>   like READ COMMITTED.

You can either change the default transaction isolation level from the MySQL option file, or else it can be enabled and disabled for a single session:

```
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
SELECT * FROM table_name;
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
```

Further Reading: [MySQL Documentation: Set Transaction](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/set-transaction.html)

Comment: ok. so not possible with myisam tables and possible with innodb talbes by setting read uncommitted?

Comment: It looks like the `READ UNCOMMITTED` isolation level will do exactly what you require in InnoDB. If you want to stick with MyISAM, note that it does not support row-level locking but only table-locks as you noticed. However it uses various types of table-locks. For example there are shared locks (Read locks) for selects, and exclusive (Write) locks for write operations. There is also a special READ LOCAL lock to allow inserts during selects.

Comment: Also note that multiple sessions can acquire a READ lock for a MyISAM table at the same time. Only write operations would get queued. If you are having many write operations, then you should really consider InnoDB. Otherwise if write operations are rare, than most probably you could stick with the default read lock on MyISAM when using selects, as this lock is not exclusive: it can be acquired by many other sessions, as long as they do not attempt a write operation.

Answer (score 1):

in the absence of LOCK TABLES, myisam should be equivalent to read uncommitted mode, but it doesn't actually support any transaction types...

innodb runs in "consistent read" mode (at "repeatable read" isolation level) by default, which the docs suggest won't lock:

> If the transaction isolation level is
>   REPEATABLE READ (the default level),
>   all consistent reads within the same
>   transaction read the snapshot
>   established by the first such read in
>   that transaction
>
> ...
>
> Consistent read is the default mode in
>   which InnoDB processes SELECT
>   statements in READ COMMITTED and
>   REPEATABLE READ isolation levels. A
>   consistent read does not set any locks
>   on the tables it accesses, and
>   therefore other sessions are free to
>   modify those tables at the same time a
>   consistent read is being performed on
>   the table.
>
> ...
>
> InnoDB uses a consistent read for
>   select in clauses like INSERT INTO ...
>   SELECT, UPDATE ... (SELECT), and
>   CREATE TABLE ... SELECT that do not
>   specify FOR UPDATE or LOCK IN SHARE
>   MODE if the
>   innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog  option
>   is set and the isolation level of the
>   transaction is not set to
>   SERIALIZABLE. Thus, no locks are set
>   on rows read from the selected table.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-consistent-read.html

Comment: ok. so you are saying that i don't even need to set the transaction level to read uncommitted for innodb tables as vasallo suggested?

sorry but i dont' understand this "in the absence of LOCK TABLES, myisam should be equivalent to read uncommitted mode"